# How to use renderAjax() directly?

Tags: yii2

I create helper without extends controller, like this

```
class SomeClass{
public function static SomeMethod(){

//this function for send email

$controller = new \yii\web\Controller();
$controller->renderAjax("template", "array");
}

}
```

how ever the above code generate `Missing argument 1 for yii\base\Controller::__construct(), called in common\component\BeoHelper.php on line 1715 and defined`

How I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
\Yii::$app->controller->renderAjax(...);
```